# Magento Newsletter Unsubscribe Link

Tags: newsletter

The link provided doesn't work! Any solution guys?

```
{{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}">{{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one in transactional emails

```
<a href="{{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}">
{{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}
</a>
```

You can also try this one

Copy the core file

> /app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php

to your local directory

> /app/code/local/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php

Open in editor to edit the code and search the function `sendConfirmationSuccessEmail()` replace the code

```
$email->sendTransactional(
    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_IDENTITY),
    $this->getEmail(),
    $this->getName(),
    array('subscriber'=>$this)
);
```

with this

```
$email->sendTransactional(
    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_IDENTITY),
    $this->getEmail(),
    $this->getName(),
    array('subscriber'=>$this, 'unsubscribe' =>$this->getUnsubscriptionLink())
);
```

and place this code in email template where you want to use unsubscribe link:

```
<a href="{{var unsubscribe}}">Unsubscribe here</a>
```

That's it!

**Update**
Potentially try `{{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}`

Comment: Thanks. But it is the same code i have already! See above in my question. This doesn't work...

Comment: Updated it maybe you can try that one

Comment: It worked for me but not with {{var unsubscribe}} but with {{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}} Thanks